# Differences between $scope.apply(); and $scope.apply(function(){});

Tags: angularjs

Take this code:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.foo = 'test';
});
```

Versus this one:

```
$scope.foo = 'test';
$scope.$apply();
```

What is the difference between those two? I tried searching but could not find any information about this.

Or even this approach:

```
$scope.$apply('foo = "test"');
```

Comment: I believe none at all

Comment: Gotta love that Angular documentation..I typically use the former, it just seems like a nicer way to keep the code, it also shows what variables you're running `.apply` on.

Comment: I think you are right. I have discovered this article: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html - Its always nice to be available to chose your coding style though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article you referenced in your comment is correct. The only difference, is that if you pass in a function, that function will be "applied" (or `$digest`ed) before the rest of the `$digest` cycle.  So if you're wanting Angular to recognize your specific change immediately (meaning before it evaluates all other changes), you should pass in a function.  Otherwise, there is no difference between `$scope.$apply()` and `$rootScope.$digest()`.

The article says the following:

> What is $apply?
>   Simply put, it's a wrapper around $rootScope.$digest that evaluates any expression passed to it prior to calling $digest(). That's it.  So, if you're calling it by itself without passing an argument to it, you may as well just call $digest().

Hope that helps.

Comment: which is recommended to use most of the time.$scope.$apply() OR $scope.$apply(fn)

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, consider the below example

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   //lets say we write some conventional JS code like
   //make an ajax call using $.ajax() of jquery
   // the code runs in angular context and exception will be thrown if any error
});
```

where as

```
$.ajax({
   // in response update the $scope.foo = 400/0 ;
}); 
$scope.$apply();
//no exception will be thrown by angular, because its unaware of what you do outside its context
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe the accepted answer is correct. When AngularJS "digests" it checks for anything that has changed in a scope since the last call to `$digest()`.

And in the case of `$apply()`, `$digest()` gets called on the `$rootScope` and therefore on all child scopes.

The only actually different between calling `$apply(function() {})` with your code in the function body and calling `$apply()` after your code, is the exception handling.

If you pass your code in as part of the function body to `$apply()` and it throws an exception, that exception will be handled by `$exceptionHandler`. Otherwise you will have to handle that exception yourself.

**What about $digest() ?**

A discussion about `$apply()` is not complete without also mentioning `$digest()`. In most cases `$digest()` is more efficient than calling `$apply()`, the reason is that `$digest()` only processes the current scope while `$apply()` processes every scope.

So if you only need your scope updated it's more efficient to call `$digest()`.

That said when you use `$digest()` you have to handle all the exceptions yourself. Unlike `$apply()`, `$digest()` doesn't do any exception handling.